# If $f \circ f$ is affine then so is $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be an open, bounded, connected subset.

Let $f:U \to U$ be a smooth map and suppose that $h:=f \circ f$ is affine (i.e. $\nabla^2h=\operatorname{Hess}h=0$).

> Is $f$ affine?

Differentiating $dh=df \circ df$, we get:
$$
0=\operatorname{Hess}h=\nabla df\circ df+ df\circ \nabla df.
$$

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: My edits to this question should make clear at least some of the diffreences are between \text{} and \operatorname{}. Even more would become clear if one contrasts \operatorname{Hess}h with $\operatorname{Hess}(h) --- the spacing to the right of "Hess" is different in those two cases, and absent entirely when \text{Hess} h is used.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Using backticks, you can show code as code, e.g. `\text{}` is produced by `‘\text{}’` with quotations replaced by backticks `.

Comment: $$
\text{Hess} h
$$
$$
\operatorname{Hess} h
$$
$$
\operatorname{Hess}(h)
$$
Notice the differences in appearance of the three expressions above, and how they're coded. Proper use of LaTeX or MathJax requires understanding of this point. But people who don't notice these things until they're pointed out walk through the same corridors that the rest of us do and look like normal humans.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for bringing this issue to my attention. I will try to use LaTeX more appropriately in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take in the complex numbers the annulus $U = \{ z ∈ ℂ;~\frac 1 2 < \lvert z \rvert < 2\}$ and $f \colon U → U,~z ↦ \frac 1 z$.

Comment: Excellent example! Also possibly worth noting is that there are also simply-connected regions that still work; $U\bigcap \{\mathfrak{R}(z)\gt 0\}$ is maybe the simplest.