# If $f \circ f$ is affine and $f$ is area-preserving, must $f$ be affine?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, area, affine-geometry

This is a follow-up of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771335/if-f-circ-f-is-affine-then-so-is-f).

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be an open, bounded, connected subset.

Let $f:U \to U$ be a smooth map. Suppose that $Jf=1$ ($f$ is area-preserving) and that $h:=f \circ f$ is affine (i.e. $\nabla^2h=\operatorname{Hess}h=0$).

> Is $f$ affine?

If we omit the requirement that $Jf=1$, then there are counter-examples:

Take in the complex numbers the annulus $U = \{ z ∈ ℂ;~\frac 1 2 < \lvert z \rvert < 2\}$ and $f \colon U → U,~z ↦ \frac 1 z$.

However, no holomorphic counter-examples are possible, if we insist on area-preservation:

Since holomorphic maps are conformal, and conformality+Jacobian $1$ implies isometry (up to a constant scaling) every holomorphic area-preserving maps is affine.

Comment: It is enough to construct a non-linear volume-preserving involution on some domain. Just map $r\mapsto \sqrt{1-r^2}$ in polar coordinates in an appropriate annulus $U$ (say, $0.6<r<0.8$, to have something explicit).

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fedja suggests in the comments, we construct an example as follows in polar coordinates:

$$
f:(r,\theta) \mapsto (\sqrt{1-r^2},-\theta).
$$

This maps $U \to U$ when $U=\{ z ∈ ℂ\, | \, 0.6 < \lvert z \rvert < 0.8\}$.

$f$ is an involution, i.e. $f^2=Id$ is affine, but $f$ is not affine